# SQL server update table with missing values

Tags: sql, sql-server, difference

I have 2 similar tables, one with all the data and the other contains a subset of the first. Every 2-3 days I need to insert in the second table the missing values, and I use this code

```
INSERT INTO [SRVDB2].[dbt].[curve].[curve_value]
SELECT *
FROM [SRVDB1].[dbt].[curve].[curve_value] as DB01
WHERE TargetDate >= '20150505'
    and NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM [SRVDB2].[dbt].[curve].[curve_value] as DB02
        WHERE DB02.TargetDate = DB01.TargetDate
            and DB02.[Hour] = DB01.[Hour]
            and DB02.[id_Mkt] = DB01.[id_Mkt]
            and DB02.[Price] = DB01.[Price]
            and DB02.VoSe = DB01.VoSe
            and DB02.VoBu = DB01.VoBu
    )
```

It always worked but now I have some rows with `NULL` in column `VoSe` or `VoBu` and those values are not inserted correctly (even if executing only the `SELECT` statement seems to return all the differences). How can I handle these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add explicit check for `NULL` for both of these columns:

```
INSERT INTO [SRVDB2].[dbt].[curve].[curve_value]
SELECT *
FROM [SRVDB1].[dbt].[curve].[curve_value] as DB01
WHERE TargetDate >= '20150505'
    and NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM [SRVDB2].[dbt].[curve].[curve_value] as DB02
        WHERE DB02.TargetDate = DB01.TargetDate
            and DB02.[Hour] = DB01.[Hour]
            and DB02.[id_Mkt] = DB01.[id_Mkt]
            and DB02.[Price] = DB01.[Price]
            and ((DB02.VoSe IS NULL AND DB01.VoSe IS NULL) OR DB02.VoSe = DB01.VoSe)
            and ((DB02.VoBu IS NULL AND DB01.VoBu IS NULL) OR DB02.VoBu = DB01.VoBu)
    )
```

Comment: I needed to add brackets `((DB02.VoSe IS NULL AND DB01.VoSe IS NULL) OR DB02.VoSe = DB01.VoSe)` and the code worked fine, thank you

Comment: @Naigel Thank you for noticing missing brackets, I updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

@dotnetom's answer (+1) should work for your problem. However, making some assumptions on the problem you describe, I suspect the following would work just as well:

```
INSERT INTO [SRVDB2].[dbt].[curve].[curve_value]
SELECT *
FROM [SRVDB1].[dbt].[curve].[curve_value]
WHERE TargetDate >= '20150505'
EXCEPT SELECT *
FROM [SRVDB2].[dbt].[curve].[curve_value]
```

Comment: I have also a TimeStamp column, so this code won't work in my specific case

Comment: That is a deal-killer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ISNULL` to handle the `NULL` values.

**NOTE:** Use some random value in `ISNULL` function which will not come in those two columns. For example i have kept 'AAA'

```
SELECT *
FROM [SRVDB1].[dbt].[curve].[curve_value] as DB01
WHERE TargetDate >= '20150505'
    and NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM [SRVDB2].[dbt].[curve].[curve_value] as DB02
        WHERE DB02.TargetDate = DB01.TargetDate
            and DB02.[Hour] = DB01.[Hour]
            and DB02.[id_Mkt] = DB01.[id_Mkt]
            and DB02.[Price] = DB01.[Price]
            and ISNULL(DB02.VoSe,'AAA') = ISNULL(DB01.VoSe,'AAA')
            and ISNULL(DB02.VoBu,'AAA') = ISNULL(DB01.VoBu,'AAA')
    )
```

Comment: this seems to be faster than @dotnetom solution